What could be the cause of a Ring Pro doorbell to keep falling offline, & then making an in home digital chime ring on it's own continuesly?
I upgraded my old Ring doorbell to a Ring Pro & once installed it stayed connected for 7 minutes before dropping offline & making my in home digital chime start ringing continuously. Tried to reset the Ring but the light will no longer light up. I returned the Ring to the store twice now & the same thing has happened with all 3 Rings within 2days. I spoke with an electrician that said it doesn't sound like an electrical issue. Please help!!

I am assuming "all 3 Rings" includes the old one. If not, does it still work when reinstalled? Have you shut off and restarted your Wi-Fi router?

The first thing I'd look at is how your doorbell is being powered. It almost sounds like your new doorbell is needing more power than your old one, and your power source can't provide the needed power after a while for your new doorbell, where it could to your old one.

What size transformer is powering the Ring?
